# How can I get rid of the sidebar pullout tab in the new Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs

The tab annoyingly covers up the scrollbar, as seen in this screenshot:

[image]

How can I disable it completely? I never want to use the sidebar, ever.

I have very few extensions.  The only relevant one is Google Docs Offline, but I still see this even what that is disabled.

I'm using Chromium on Linux Mint 19 in this case.

Comment: I don't see that pullout tab. What operative system and  web browser are you using (please include name and version)? Have you already tried on a different web browser and on private/incognito mode with all the extensions disabled?

Comment: I was able to see the pullout tab o Gmail and Google Documents, Slides but not on Google Sheets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove it with **[Adblock Plus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock-plus-free-ad-bloc/cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb)**' feature **Block element**:

```
docs.google.com##.companion-collapser-button-container
```

[image: 0]

[image: 0]

Comment: Fantastic, that did it!  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there isn't an opt-out setting for the new Google Apps side panel.

The alternatives are

- A [userscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Userscript) to collapse the side panel and then to hide the switcher.
- A web browser extension that does the above
- Send feedback to Google by using [Google Feedback](https://www.google.com/tools/feedback/) and wait.

Comment: I've sent feedback to them.  I appreciate your alternatives here, but since this is a "there's no direct solution" answer I'll wait a day or two to see if anyone else has something; if nobody does I'll accept your answer.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Had this issue as well...

Go to the vertical ellipse (three vertical dots in top right corner). Go to more tools-> Developer tools. Make sure the 'Elements' tab is clicked and hit any part of the HTML code. Next hold CTRL+F (the find option) and a search bar will appear. Search for "show side panel". Go through the search (my search came up with two results) and pick the code segment that highlights the tab. Right click on the html code and choose hide element and that should take care of it.

You can repeat the search and type 'explore' and hide the element to take care of that tab as well. Hope this helps.

Comment: Neat approach, but this will have to be redone every time I open a doc, right?